# frontdoor.jsp for Customer Portal user? How to authenticate a portal user with session id?

Tags: rest-api, soap-api, customer-portal, soap, authentication

1. authenticate a customer portal using SOAP login() method and LoginScopeHeader
2. receive SessionID in LoginResult object
3. **How can I use SessionID to redirect the user's browser to the customer portal and log them in?**

I've tried frontdoor.jsp, but it's not working.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This discussion forum thread](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F00000009A7rIAE) suggests that you can do this with

```
https://<instance>.salesforce.com/secur/frontdoor.jsp?sid=<sessionId>&orgId=<orgId>&portalId=<portalId>
```

Change `<instance>` to the relevant instance, e.g. na1, and substitute in the relevant IDs.

Comment: Does this works with communities ? I can't see a clear way to get community id. I tried copying it from the Setup > Communities > All Communities and "Manage" link. My URL after SOAP API login comes out to be :  https://cs21.salesforce.com/secur/frontdoor.jsp?sid=00Dq0000000ARcu%21....&orgId=00Dq0000000ARcuEAG&portalId=0DBq00000000098 but this is not working out for me. +metadaddy any suggestions ?

Comment: From [Knowledge Article Number: 000193348](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000193348&language=en_US): "Note that frontdoor.jsp login is not supported for Salesforce Communities. It has been restricted due to security risk. For seamless login from customer's website to Salesforce Communities, suggested approach is to use SAML based Single Sign-On ."