# Log in to Community with OAuth Access Token

Tags: community, oauth2, jwt

I am getting an access token using JWT Bearer Token Flow.  I'm trying to log in to a Community through "frontdoor.jsp" with the token.  Looking at [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33621/frontdoor-jsp-for-customer-portal-user-how-to-authenticate-a-portal-user-with-s), it doesn't look possible.  But [the help article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000193348&type=1) title now says "Use frontdoor.jsp to login to Salesforce and Communities".  It looks to be modified and no longer has the following text - "Note that frontdoor.jsp login is not supported for Salesforce Communities. It has been restricted due to security risk. For seamless login from customer's website to Salesforce Communities, suggested approach is to use SAML based Single Sign-On ."

Has the behavior changed recently?  Is it now possible to log in to Community with OAuth access token? During my tests, the log in still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

The help article you have has been updated. You can now get access and get logged into the community using the access token you received using the JWT Bearer Token Flow through frontdoor.jsp as long as you have a **web scoped access token**.

You shouldn't need to use frontdoor to get access to your community since you already have an access token though. But for anyone that wants to get the refresh token, you will pass it into frontdoor.jsp with parameters sid and retURL to your authorization endpoint. Frontdoor.jsp will return you an authorization code which you can pass onto the token endpoint to get the access token/refresh token. Hope this helps!